# How do you install a CLDC Platform in NetBeans 7.2?

Tags: java, java-me

for an hour now, i've been trying to find a way to install the CLDC Oracle Java Platform in my Netbeans 7.2.
can someone help me? i'm sort of loosing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

In this Oracle [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamesdk/entry/java_me_sdk_3_01) says that there are issues with 7.2 (see last comments), they recommend to use Netbeans 7.1.2 or the upcoming 7.2.1

Comment: i am now aware, but one of my schoolmates managed to stay using 7.2 and had no problem using J2ME with it. sigh.

Answer (score 0):

Just read this page http://netbeans.org/community/releases/36/J2ME_Support.html .... You will find the way to install J2me support in your netbeans.